# Orange peel effect does not work

Tags: materials

Hello I'm trying to create a car paint material like in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUV6gzlMDdI):

[image: video screenshot]

but the orange peel effect does not work even though I do everything exactly the same way.

[image: shader nodes]

Blend file: https://mega.nz/file/pakH1AgT#7fep0eH_AohHfx3bIFbrKgWJVZWSamx2j2-nrZQ4Fws

I'm a Mac user, maybe it's the settings

Does somebody have any idea?

thanks

Comment: Hello Kirill, could you please add some screenshots of your material setup and a Blender file so we can troubleshoot it? 
https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I suspect that he may be working with an object (the car) which is a different size to your cube.  Try changing the Distance in the Bump node to 0.0001 and the Scale in the Noise texture to 100 and see what happens. You can also apply the scale to the cube with Ctrl-A which might help. - Those settings work in Blender 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's the scale of your model (the cube). If you compare the size of the *Voronoi* pattern as shown in the video to your material preview you will see the difference.

**Video** ...
[image: video screenshot]

... **vs Cube**

[image: cube screenshot]

To fix this, **(1)** apply the *Scale* to your object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode) and **(2)** increase the *Scale* value of the *Mapping* node to something like `10`. You can leave the *Scale* value of the *Noise Texture* node and the *Voronoi* node at `15` but maybe **(3)** increase the *Distance* value of the *Bump* node to `0.00005`.

Then you have an orange peel effect (the distorted light reflection **(4)**) like this:
[image: final result]

Comment: Thank you very mach, sometimes it's so simple but you can't figure it out.