# Materials Issue: Weird Geometric Normals

Tags: materials, normals, geometry, normal-map, reflection

[image]
[image]

Whenever I apply normals to an object, it gives me this bizarre mapping and reflection that follows the object's geometry. I don't know what's causing it. Hoping to get it fixed.

Comment: Hello, are you sure that you don't need a Bump node before the Clearcoat Normal input?

Comment: Here is a similar question that uses a *Bump* node to create an orange peel effect for a car paint: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/279709/107598