# Spherical Rainbow Glitter material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, normal-map

Does anyone know how to replicate this pattern in cycles?

[image]

I've been keeping it simple by just saying that every one of these flakes is a perfect circle (though they clearly aren't) and generating these circles with a voronoi texture. I was generating a wave texture with a color ramp to use for the rainbow effect, but I have very little control over which flakes are emissive/highly reflective, and which are not. I've played with plugging the circles into a normal map, but I'm still not getting the contrast in reflectivity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think the normal input slot can use the black & white input that you provide. If you want to create a custom/artistic normal map to simulate tilted flakes you need a *Normal Map* node and modify then the color input - or use a *Bump* node.

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea that was bugging me, and it took three tries. Here is the final version. It's still not a perfect match because unlike the reference the dots are not monochrome but multicolored if you look closely. But I think it's very close to the reference.

[image: example render Cycles]
<sup>Example render (Cycles)</sup>

I used your idea to create the dots/flakes through a *Voronoi* texture. Then they are stacked in 5 layers where each background layer is a bit darker to simulate 3D depth.

The dots can be created using *Voronoi > Distance* output and the help of a *Color Ramp* or *Map Range* node. This is also a mask for the *Mix* node. The *Voronoi > Color* output gives each dot its own color. The problem with this is that I want the individual dots to be solid colors, but in the overall image I want them to match the background texture (the "rainbow"). I have no idea how to realize this, so I leave them multicolored, that is, I just mix them with the background.

[image: glittering dots shader]
<sup>Glittering dots shader</sup>

So mix the background with the created dots and the result is again used as background for the next layer. Darkening is done with the help of a *Hue/Saturation/Value* node. The dots of the last layer are lightened and slightly desaturated to make them shine more.

To organize the nodes, group the nodes that will be used to create a single dot layer. Now it is better to use a *Map Range* node instead of a *Color Ramp* because you want to control the values from outside the group.

[image: Glitter Dots shader group]
<sup>Glitter Dots shader group</sup>

The "artistic" normal map is generated by separating the color channels, keeping blue at 1 and randomizing the red and green channels. Here is a similar question for even more glittering: [Orange peel effect does not work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/279709/107598)

The color of the default "flat" normal map is HEX 8080FF.

[image: glare nodes for the compositor]
<sup>Glare nodes for the compositor</sup>

Last but not least, use a HDRI as world background, and activate the Bloom effect for Eevee. For Cycles, it's better to use one or two glare nodes in the compositor.